# MySQL: Inner JOIN and Outer JOIN on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have multiple tables:

**A, B, C, D**

I want Inner JOINs on A,B,C and Outer JOIN of the result with D.

I guess the obvious way to do is (skipping SELECT statements):

```
(A JOIN B JOIN C ON ...) table_alias 
LEFT JOIN D ON ...
```

But I was wondering if I could do something like:

```
A 
JOIN B 
JOIN C 
LEFT JOIN D ON ...
```

I don't think MySQL likes it. Please let me know if there's a better way.

Thanks!

Comment: I've used your second form many times, why don't you think it likes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could nest joins like this also:

```
SELECT * FROM A JOIN (B, C) ON (A.a=B.a AND B.b=C.b) LEFT JOIN D ON C.c=D.c
```

Answer (score 0):

The `from` clause you want can be expressed as:

```
FROM A JOIN
     B
     ON . . . JOIN
     C
     ON . . . LEFT JOIN
     D
     ON . . .
```

You do not need parentheses in MySQL to express this.